# PostgreSQL merge two queries with COUNT and GROUP BY in each

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, crosstab

1st query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', date1) as date, COUNT(*) AS count_a 
FROM table_a GROUP BY date
```

result:

```
date                    count_a
2014-04-01 00:00:00.0   1011642
2014-04-02 00:00:00.0   309048
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', date1) as date, COUNT(*) AS count_b 
FROM table_b GROUP BY date
```

result:

```
date                    count_b
2014-04-01 00:00:00.0   2342
2014-04-02 00:00:00.0   43432
```

I'd like to get:

```
date                    count_a  count_b
2014-04-01 00:00:00.0   1011642  2342
2014-04-02 00:00:00.0   309048   43432
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple UNION ALL should make it possible.

```
SELECT date1 date, SUM(a) count_a, SUM(b) count_b 
FROM (
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', date1) date1, 1 a, 0 b FROM table_a 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', date1) date1, 0 a, 1 b FROM table_b
) z 
GROUP BY date;
```

EDIT: [Here's an SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/090ab/1).

Comment: great answer! this is what i need it. thanks sir

Answer (score 9):

Use [**`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT date1::date AS day, COUNT(*) AS count_a
   FROM   table_a
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT date1::date AS day, COUNT(*) AS count_b
   FROM   table_b
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) b USING (day);
```

- The `USING` clause automatically folds to *one* column `day` in the result.
- To get dates just cast to `date`. Faster, simpler.

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/090ab/4) (based on Joachim's).

Minor difference: this query returns `NULL` for days without any rows on one side. Use **`COALESCE(count_b, 0)`** to get `0` instead.